# Using the Adafruit RFM69HCW Transceiver Radio Bonnet on a Pico?

Tags: pi-pico, radio

I have not acquired the components yet to try this, so I'm asking first simply if anyone has already done this (not the "how" details).

Adafruit makes a RFM69HCW Transceiver Radio Bonnet for the Pi series of SBCs.  I'm wondering if this would also work for the Pico microcontroller.  There are several (Red Robotics’ Pico 2 Pi Adaptor; SB Components’ Pi HAT Expansion Based on Pico) solutions available for physically mapping the Pico's split 20-pin header configuration into the Pi SBC 2x20-pin header configuration.  This would allow the Radio hat to be matched to a Pico.  But I don't know if the companion library "adafruit-circuitpython-rfm69" will work in a Pico, or would require a porting beyond my current level of experience.

I apologize in advance for the theoretical nature of my question with no hard observations to support it.  I know there are other radio solutions out there, but this one appears to be the most "compact" which is why I am focusing on it.  (I want to set up a com link between two Pi Zeros or Picos at a distance beyond wifi.)

Comment: Why ask here instead of the Adafruit forums? The pinout of the Pi vs Pico is more than just splitting the rails apart.

Comment: There are 'non-bonnet' versions of these modules with Circuitpython modules also available. See e.g. https://www.adafruit.com/product/3071, I would expect these to be pico compatible, but I would check with Adafruit to make sure.

Comment: I don't know **why** you are considering these, but if it's because you think you'll get greater distance, be sure to read this: `The RFM69 radios have a range of approx. 500 meters line of sight with tuned uni-directional antennas.` [REF](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-rfm69hcw-and-rfm96-rfm95-rfm98-lora-packet-padio-breakouts)